# Space after exercise

Tags: vertical-alignment, xsim

The following example is of an exercise followed by a paragraph:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xsim}
\begin{document}
\begin{exercise}
This is some text for an exercise.
\end{exercise}

And now a paragraph to test if there is a break.
\end{document}
```

This produces a document where there is no space between the end of the exercise and the next paragraph. I realise I could add space with something like `\medskip` written manually after each exercise, but this doesn't seem idiomatic. What is the best way to ensure that every exercise is followed by a skip? This ought to be smart enough not to skip if the exercise is followed by a solution.

Comment: There is an option called `exercise/after-hook` (or similar, I can't remember exactly... It's in the manual) which you could use to add `\medskip` at the end of each exercise.

Comment: Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `post-hook`, but I'd not recommend `\medskip`, because such a space would pile up with the space preceding another exercise.

However, `\addvspace{\medskipamount}` does not work, because LaTeX has not yet ended a paragraph when the `post-hook` code is inserted. And, unfortunately, `\par\addvspace{\medskipamount}` does not work either, because `\xsimsetup` does not accept `\par` in its argument. `:-(`

You can define a new template based on the default one, perhaps also demoting `\subsection*` to `\subsubsection*` to give less prominence.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xsim}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate {wu}
  {
    \subsubsection*
      {
        \XSIMmixedcase { \GetExerciseName } \nobreakspace
        \GetExerciseProperty {counter}
        \IfInsideSolutionF
          {
            \IfExercisePropertySetT {subtitle}
              { ~ { \normalfont \itshape \GetExerciseProperty {subtitle} } }
          }
      }
    \GetExercisePropertyT {points}
      {
        \marginpar
          {
            \IfInsideSolutionF { \rule {1.2cm} {1pt} \slash }
            \printgoal {\PropertyValue}
            \GetExercisePropertyT {bonus-points}
              { \nobreakspace ( + \printgoal {\PropertyValue} ) }
            \nobreakspace\XSIMtranslate {point-abbr}
          }
      }
  }
  {\par\addvspace{\medskipamount}}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\xsimsetup{exercise/template=wu}


\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}
This is some text for an exercise.
\end{exercise}

And now a paragraph to test if there is a break.

\begin{exercise}
This is some text for an exercise.
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}
This is some text for an exercise.
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, the space between Exercise 2 and Exercise 3 is the same as the space before Exercise 2.

Comment: The default template will get a `\par` at the end in the next version. And also the argument of `\xsimsetup` will become long :) I'll make the upload to CTAN later today

Comment: @clemens Maybe also a hook for the header? With default value `\subsection*`, but that can be changed with `x\xsimsetup` to some other command.

Comment: that's a good idea

Comment: Nice answer: I was bothered by the `\medskip` adding superfluous space! I also had no idea why `\addvspace` wasn't working: thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @clemens in the comment, it is possible to add code into a post hook. Here is what the fix looks like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xsim}
\xsimsetup{exercise/post-hook={\medskip}}
\begin{document}
\begin{exercise}
This is some text for an exercise.
\end{exercise}
And now a paragraph to test if there is a break.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
exercise/end-hook = {<code>}
```

The code for the **end exercise** hook for exercises of the type “exercise”.

```
exercise/post-hook = {<code>}
```

The code for the **post exercise** hook for exercises of the type “exercise”.

Method **a**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xsim}
\xsimsetup{exercise/end-hook={\medskip}}

\begin{document}
\begin{exercise}
This is some text for an exercise.
\end{exercise}
And now a paragraph to test if there is a break.
\end{document}
```

Method **b**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xsim}

\usepackage{etoolbox} 
\AfterEndEnvironment{exercise}{\medskip}

\begin{document}
\begin{exercise}
This is some text for an exercise.
\end{exercise}
And now a paragraph to test if there is a break.
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Edit:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xsim}
\xsimsetup{exercise/end-hook={\vskip\baselineskip}}

\begin{document}
\begin{exercise}
This is some text for an exercise.
\end{exercise}
And now a paragraph to test if there is a break.
\end{document}
```

OR:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox} 
\AfterEndEnvironment{exercise}{\vskip\baselineskip}
```

Output edit:

[image]